How to translate "There is nothing to it," into Latin
Trying to translate this phrase which portrays the idea of something being seen as easy, my initial opinion of how this should be translated was," ei nihil est.
Ei would obviously be an indirect object but the original English form doesn't portray the function of "to it" as an indirect object even in the preceding word, is "to".
Another possible translation I configured was,"de eo nihil est. I was hoping this would  put forth the idea of like "concerning" or "about." With a full translation being as follows," There is nothing concerning it."
Although these ideas somewhat get the point across, I feel like neither of them properly portray the original intent of the English statement. Could anybody offer any other translations which represent my original intent better than my options?

This is probably a case where you should look at the broader context of what you want to say, and try to find a way to express the idea within that context. It is generally not ideal to look for a set Latin phrase that will fit as a translation for a set English phrase in all circumstances. And it is completely hopeless to try to translate an expression like “there is nothing to it” by translating its components individually, that cannot work except by pure chance.
That said, “it takes X to do Y” can often be expressed by est + genetive, such as magni est ingenii sevocare mentem a sensibus (Cic. Tusc. 1, 38) – it takes a great genius to separate the mind from the senses.
Now if we have some idea what it is specifically that's not required for some achievement – say, strength, skill, intelligence – we can negate this construction. Take this example from Quintilian (Inst. 5, 13, 16):

Palam contraria et supervacua et stulta reprehendere nullius est artis
It takes no skill to refute what is plain contradictory, superfluous or stupid

Based on this, you should be able to find a translation that fits your needs.

I wish your initial paragraph could be shouted from the rooftops far and wide. It should be the first lesson of every class in which a language is taught to new students.

Quintilian may have underestimated the difficulty of countering misinformation
